# Do spam bots can see microdata tag?

Tags: email, spam, microdata

For example I need to hide my email from spam bots,
if I use

```
<meta itemprop="email" content="myemail@domain.com"/>
```

in html code.
Is it safe from spam bots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll find bots that parse it, you’ll find bots that don’t parse it, you’ll find bots that parse the whole source code looking for *anything@anything*.

Bots would be stupid to ignore Microdata/RDFa.